# Problem saving 4 bytes emojis in mysql using java

Tags: java, mysql

I have no problem saving an emoji in my DB directly, when I run:

`UPDATE mgEngTest.push t SET t.text = 'yes ' WHERE t.id = 6816`

works fine!

But when I try to do it from my java code I get:

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9F\x98\x83' for column 'title' at row 1`
Only when I try with 4 bytes characters, for instance: if I have '\xF0\x9F\x98' works fine.

this is my DB info:

[image: this is my DB info]

this is my table info:
[image: this is my table info:]

I have mysql-connector version: 8.0.16

When I tried with my mysql db local I can do it without problems.

Comment: Working query puts values in column called `text` and the one that fails tries to put values into a column called `title` Is this a Apples and Oranges TYPO issue

Comment: “when I try to do it from my java code…” Edit your question and show us that code (as pasted text, not as an image).  We can’t provide suggestions for it if we can’t see it.

Comment: Judging by [this](https://mathiasbynens.be/notes/mysql-utf8mb4) you have the settings correct. I'd guess either the server version is too old, or possibly you're connecting with bad configurations.